# Sharing a file with file path in Android / Getting a working uri from file path

Tags: android, uri, share, action-send

I'm trying to share a file with other apps (e.g. Telegram, Whatapp, etc) using:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It works if the uri is from an ACTION_GET_CONTENT activity. But I have only a path to the file I want to share and if I set:

```
uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path))
```

everything seems OK but the file is not sent in the last step.

How can I get a working uri from a file path?

Comment: Use `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

hope this code will help you!

```
 ApplicationInfo api = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
                    String apkPath = api.sourceDir;
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Via"));
```